# GPU Core Clock Seems Wrong

Tags: windows, gpu

My GPU core clock is way lower than it should be. I'm using Unity but this happens in games and other apps. The usage says 100% but the core clock is a measly 250mhz. What could cause this?

Windows 11 x64 latest patches and updates.
GeForce 3080 TI, latest driver as of Sept. 15, 2022.

[image]

Comment: Did you connect your monitor to your onboard graphics by accident?

Comment: Did you install crapware like RoG software or Armoury Crate? They might be putting your GPU in some sort of "Eco" mode.

Comment: Check your Windows power settings to make sure you're not in some low power mode.

Comment: Does a restart fix it? Maybe do a clean re-install of the nVidia drivers.

Comment: Restart does not help unfortunately. Also tried max performance power mode. I did install armoury crate, but looks like I re-installed Windows a few months ago and I did not put it back. No onboard gpu. Will try reinstall of nvidia.

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop? What is the CPU? Check the Nvidia control panel for maximum performance mode. Does your graphics card have a dual-BIOS? Maybe it's stuck in low performance mode at the hardware level. Does the core clock ever exceed 250? Has it in the past? Is this a new symptom?

Comment: Desktop. MSI z690 pro. Intel 12900K, not overclocked. 128gb RAM. It seems like this symptom appeared within the last month or two. The clock sometimes goes to 300, or 350 range but then snaps back to the 250 range.

Comment: I once had a free trial of Norton Antivirus enabled while I did a Prime95 CPU stress test and Norton throttled my CPU to 50% because it thought my laptop was compromised. Maybe your antivirus thinks you have a crypto-mining virus?

Comment: No anti-virus installed (other than Windows defender). Cinebench test gives an expected score so I think the CPU at least is not being throttled.

Comment: FYI, you do have an onboard GPU. The i9-12900K sports Intel® UHD Graphics 770. Your motherboard even has an HDMI and DisplayPort so double-check that your monitor is not plugged into the motherboard but rather the RTX 3080TI

Comment: Interesting. Yes my cable is plugged into the gpu card.

Comment: Check the Windows Event Viewer, specifically Windows Logs -> Application. It could reveal that something is silently crashing.

Comment: How long have you been using this 3080TI? It's possible that it developed a defect.

Comment: Since January, that will be my option is to replace it after troubleshooting a few things

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to check this for your specific setup but this [forum post](https://forums.evga.com/RTX-3080ti-stuck-at-210-MHz-while-gaming-after-latest-driver-install-m3570492.aspx) suggests "Check and make sure your power limit isn't set to something super low."

Comment: Also, you should check if a new motherboard BIOS has been released.

Comment: Looks like it was evga precision lol. Uninstalling that pos. I don't remember installing it, but I must have at some point in the last few months. Maybe to try and turn off the leds on the card. Full power has been restored :)

Comment: Gotta love crapware!

Comment: I'll add an answer if you'd be so kind as to mark it as accepted =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check and make sure that crapware like Armoury Crate or EVGA Precision didn't put your GPU into some sort of "Eco mode" or reduced power limit.

Comment: Thank you for the good answer.